# how can i write dynamically text in head tag header.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on plugin, i want to write a text line between head tag in header.php

For example:

when a user install and activate the plugin.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/foo/foo_style.css" />
```

will automatically include in header.php

any idea.

Comment: you need to use wp_head action hook .see the link for more details
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head

Comment: i am doing this add_action('wp_head', 'foo_article_style');
function foo_article_style(){
    wp_register_style('foo_theme_css', get_template_directory().'/foo/foo_style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('foo_theme_css');
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the wp_enqueue_style options for that.

Something like this (not tested):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadCSS' );

function loadCSS() {
    wp_register_style( 'myPluginStylesheet', plugins_url('stylesheet.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'myPluginStylesheet' );
}
```

See for more information: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

And please, make the addition of your styles optional :-)

Comment: bro i want to add in theme folder not in plugin folder

Comment: This one is adding a css in the head of the theme template. The css resides in your plugin folder. That's what you want, isn't it?

Comment: Or maybe just follow this tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins--wp-24321

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
if (is_plugin_active('plugin-directory-path/plugin-file.php')) {
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/foo/foo_style.css" />
}
```

`is_plugin_active()` will check whether a plugin is activated or not

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
function my_scripts() {

if (is_plugin_active('plugin-directory/plugin.php')) {
      wp_enqueue_style( 'plugin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/yourplugin.css', false, '1.0', 'all' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```